# WebDriverError ao executar testes E2E com Protractor/Selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, testes-automatizados, jasmine, e2e

Está ocorrendo o erro abaixo ao executar os specs de testes E2E, não foi feito nenhuma ação anteriormente que possa ter causado o erro.

Esse é o erro:

```
[14:20:03] I/testLogger -  PID: 16221
 Specs: /slave/workspace/painel-web-e2e/angularjs/test/e2e/views/firefox/emissao/componentes/emissao-comp-pesq-simples.spec.js

 (node:16221) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
 [14:19:55] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub

 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:445
             throw new error.WebDriverError(
                   ^
 WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {
   "value": {
     "sessionId": "7217f88a9df73d5c856e9073bfb8da29",
     "capabilities": {
       "acceptInsecureCerts": false,
       "browserName": "chrome",
       "browserVersion": "75.0.3770.90",
       "chrome": {
         "chromedriverVersion": "75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs\u002fbranch-heads\u002f3770@{#1003})",
         "userDataDir": "\u002ftmp\u002f.com.google.Chrome.OlgJlr"
       },
       "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "debuggerAddress": "localhost:34780"
       },
       "networkConnectionEnabled": false,
       "pageLoadStrategy": "normal",
       "platformName": "linux",
       "proxy": {
       },
       "setWindowRect": true,
       "strictFileInteractability": false,
       "timeouts": {
         "implicit": 0,
         "pageLoad": 300000,
         "script": 30000
       },
       "unhandledPromptBehavior": "dismiss and notify",
       "webdriver.remote.sessionid": "7217f88a9df73d5c856e9073bfb8da29"
     }
   }
 }
     at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:445:19)
     at <anonymous>
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
 From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
     at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
     at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
     at createDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:167:33)
     at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:623:16)
     at Hosted.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.ts:60:29)
     at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
     at q.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
     at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
     at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)

[14:20:03] I/testLogger - 

[14:20:03] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[14:20:03] I/launcher - 8 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[14:20:03] I/testLogger -
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi usando o **npm install -g protractor** e  **webdriver-manager update**